# Swift - NSURLSession for Windows Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, nsurlsession

I have this class here and inside the class is a method and I am trying to do an NSURLSession on an API that requires windows authentication username and password. I have followed the tutorial here https://gist.github.com/n8armstrong/5c5c828f1b82b0315e24

and came up with this:

```
let webservice = "https://api.com"

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

class WebService: NSObject {

    func loginUser(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

        let userPasswordString = "username@domain.com:Password"
        let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"

        config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

        let requestString = NSString(format:"%@", webservice) as String
        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: requestString)

        let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in
            if (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse) != nil {
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)
            }
        }

        task.resume()

        return true

    }

}
```

but when I run this I get a 401 error: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

I have confirmed the URL to the API is correct. Same with the username and password. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing the following:

```
var credential: NSURLCredential!

    func loginUser(username: String, password: String) -> Bool {

        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        credential = NSURLCredential(user:username, password:password, persistence: .ForSession)

        let requestString = NSString(format:"%@", webservice) as String
        let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: requestString)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    print("Yay!")
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Naw!")
                }

            })

        })

        task.resume()

        return true

    }
```

and then adding NSURLSessionDelegate methods:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0
        {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.CancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        }

    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential,credential)

    }
```

Comment: Right.  You should avoid overriding the Authorization header, because NSURLSession reserves the right to stomp on it.  In some cases, you can get around this by using X-Authorization or similar, depending on what the service supports, but the right way to do basic auth is to create the credential and let the OS handle it as you did.